# Uncaught ReferenceError: isAuthenticated is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I am trying to use AuthO to sucessfully setup a login system on my website but i am using components in react and the tutorial they have setup use a different method, so i tried a work around by creating a function and trying to run it through that but it seems my isAuthenticated object is still bugging out, here is my various code.

Top of Navbar.js

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    <Authenticated />
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar
```

Where isAuthenticated is used

```
{!isAuthenticated && (
    <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}>Log in</button>
)}

{isAuthenticated && <button onClick={() => logout()}>Log out</button>}
```

Authenticated function used to bypass components issue:

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "../../react-auth0-spa.js";

function Authenticated(){
  const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();
}

export default Authenticated;
```

Even with all of this it is still not working and am getting the following errors, ignore the second error:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqReF.png)

Comment: Also, have you followed the steps here? This documentation is for React https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react#configure-auth0 Try this out!

Comment: @SiddheshT Yes thats the exact tutorial i followed and got this error

Comment: What is the code at line 249 in NavBar.jsx at which it is giving the error? Make sure that there is a reference for isAuthenticated available before that line...